# How do I get the correct result without having a column in group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a small issue which I am not able to wrap my head around.

I have a dataset which is pretty easy to understand

Table 1 - Batch

| ID | Type | ReceivedOn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1033 | Framed | 2021-06-05 |
| 1300 | Frameless | 2021-06-05 |
| XL1000 | Various | 2021-06-05 |
| XLF1000 | Various | 2021-06-05 |
| 1034 | Framed | 2021-06-05 |
| 1301 | Frameless | 2021-06-06 |
| XL1001 | Various | 2021-06-06 |
| XLF1001 | Various | 2021-06-06 |

Table 2 - Orders

| ID | BatchID | Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1033 | OrderExample |
| 2 | 1033 | OrderExample |
| 3 | 1300 | OrderExample |
| 4 | XL1000 | OrderExample |
| 5 | XL1000 | OrderExample |
| 6 | XL1000 | OrderExample |
| 7 | XL1000 | OrderExample |
| 8 | XLF1000 | OrderExample |
| 9 | XLF1000 | OrderExample |
| 10 | XLF1000 | OrderExample |
| 11 | XLF1000 | OrderExample |
| 12 | XLF1000 | OrderExample |
| 13 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 14 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 15 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 16 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 17 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 18 | 1034 | OrderExample |
| 19 | 1301 | OrderExample |
| 20 | 1301 | OrderExample |
| 21 | 1301 | OrderExample |
| 22 | XL1001 | OrderExample |
| 23 | XL1001 | OrderExample |
| 24 | XLF1001 | OrderExample |
| 25 | XLF1001 | OrderExample |
| 26 | XLF1001 | OrderExample |

**What I am trying to achieve**

I want to create a report that tells me the following

Framed - 8 Orders

Frameless - 4 Orders

Various Manufactures Framed (notice the BatchID does not have F in it) - 6 Orders

Various Manufactures Frameless (BatchID that has F in it) - 8 orders

What I have so far is a query where I can group by Framed, Frameless and Frameless Manufactures.

**What I want**

| Type | # Of Orders |
| --- | --- |
| Framed | 8 Orders |
| Frameless | 4 Orders |
| Various Manufactures Framed | 6 Orders |
| Various Manufactures Frameless | 8 orders |

I want to have the various manufactures sub divided based on what is the BatchID. If I add the batch ID and group by it, it breaks the entire report by each Batch ID.

Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Hi @ParthKadakia please provide a snapshot of your expectation if possible.

Comment: @RahulBiswas - I have edited the question with a table of what I would like..

Comment: Why without GROUP BY?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that there is no other type where BatchId contains 'F' then maybe something like this could work.

```
select 
    case 
        when batch_id like '%F%' then 'Various Manufactures Frameless'
        when type  = 'Various' then 'Various Manufactures Framed'
        else type
    end as type,
    count(o.id)
from Batch b
    left outer join Orders o on o.batch_id = b.id
group by case 
    when batch_id like '%F%' then 'Various Manufactures Frameless'
    when type = 'Various' then 'Various Manufactures Framed'
    else type
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are attempting to join the two tables and then implement a GROUP BY function to count each instance of a type that received an order.

You could try as follows:

```
select t1.Type, count(*) from Batch as t1 inner join Orders as t2 on t1.ID=t2.BatchID group by t1.Type;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the 'Various' type gets subdivided I would classify non-'Various' types in the first WHEN condition of the CASE expression.

```
select case when type<>'Various' then type
            when batch_id like '%F%' then 'Various Manufactures Frameless'
            else 'Various Manufactures Framed'
            end as [Type],
       count(o.id) [# Of Orders]
from Batch b
     join Orders o on o.batch_id = b.id
group by case when type<>'Various' then type
              when batch_id like '%F%' then 'Various Manufactures Frameless'
              else 'Various Manufactures Framed'
              end;
```

For the record here it is WITHOUT GROUP BY

```
with
rn_cte as (
    select b.id, v.type_grp, o.BatchID, row_number() over (partition by v.type_grp order by o.id) rn
    from #Batch b
         join #Orders o on o.batchid = b.id
         cross apply (values (case when type<>'Various' then type
                                   when batchid like '%F%' then 'Various Manufactures Frameless'
                                   else 'Various Manufactures Framed'
                                   end)) v(type_grp)),
max_cte as (
    select id, type_grp, BatchID, rn, max(rn) over (partition by type_grp order by rn desc) max_over
    from rn_cte
    )
select type_grp [Type], max_over [# Of Orders]
from max_cte
where rn=1;
```

It could also be done using SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES